# Rock Paper Scissors - Python 3 - beginner

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I'm suppose to simulate a rock paper scissors game and this is what I have so far. It's not letting me input letters into the `scoregame` function. How can I fix this?

```
def scoregame(player1, player2):
    if player1 == R and player2 == R:
        scoregame = "It's a tie, nobody wins."
    if player1 == S and player2 == S:
        scoregame == "It's a tie, nobody wins."
    if player1 == P and player2 == P:
        scoregame = "It's a tie, nobody wins."
    if player1 == R and player2 == S:
        scoregame = "Player 1 wins."
    if player1 == S and player2 == P:
        scoregame = "Player 1 wins."
    if player1 == P and player2 == R:
        scoregame = "Player 1 wins."
    if player1 == R and player2 == P:
        scoregame == "Player 2 wins."
    if player1 == S and player2 == R:
        scoregame == "Player 2 wins."
    if player1 == P and player2 == S:
        scoregame = "Player 2 wins."

print(scoregame)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that takes the input and shows `scoregame`? Because from the description, and the last line, I suspect you've got those wrong too. Also, please describe the problem. What do you mean "it's not letting me input letters". Does it raise an exception as soon as you run the program? When it calls the `scoregame` function? Inside the `scoregame` function? If so, give us the exception and traceback. Or does it run successfully, but do the wrong thing? If so, describe your input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Also, as a side note, using the same name for your function and a variable isn't actually _incorrect_ in this case, but it's confusing, and it's better to avoid it.

Comment: @abarnert I think maybe preference, since I also do this. It is easy to understand that this will be the output/returned thing usually.

Comment: @Dualinity: One day you're going to write a recursive function that returns a function and have a fun time debugging it. :)

Comment: Please don't deface your questions. I've rolled that edit back.

Comment: @BradLarson: The OP [suggested a similar defacement on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3051138).

Answer (score 5):

You need to test against *strings*; you are now testing against variable names:

```
if player1 == 'R' and player2 == 'R':
```

but you can simplify the case where both players picked the same option by testing if they are equal:

```
if player1 == player2:
    scoregame = "It's a tie, nobody wins."
```

Next, I'd use a mapping, a dictionary, to codify what beats what:

```
beats = {'R': 'S', 'S': 'P', 'P': 'R'}

if beats[player1] == player2:
    scoregame = "Player 1 wins."
else:
    scoregame = "Player 2 wins."
```

Now your game can be tested in just 2 tests. All put together:

```
def scoregame(player1, player2):
    beats = {'R': 'S', 'S': 'P', 'P': 'R'}
    if player1 == player2:
        scoregame = "It's a tie, nobody wins."
    elif beats[player1] == player2:
        scoregame = "Player 1 wins."
    else:
        scoregame = "Player 2 wins."
    print(scoregame)
```

Comment: If he uses `elif` instead of `if`, he can reduce the whole thing to just 5 clauses. But you're right, the dictionary lets him reduce it to 3, and is harder to get wrong.

Comment: @jerry2144: why the defacement? If you used my post in your homework, then that's your problem, not mine. Please do not vandalize my work because it embarasses you.

Comment: The funny thing is that, if his teacher had googled for the first line of your version of the code, this question would have been the first search result anyway. So, instead of being evidence that the student came up with exactly the same code as you (which proves nothing, since it's the obvious way to write it…), it's now evidence that the student intentionally copied and pasted the code and then tried to cover it up. (This is why I don't understand teachers who hate SO…)

Answer (score 1):

You are using letters without quotes so its looking for a *Variable* called P but what you want is a *String* "P" so put the letters in quotes:

```
if player1 == "P" and player2 == "S":
```